# What type of object is this? XML Serialize/Deserialize

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio

I have an XML file that I'm deserializing which works pretty well.

I'm struggling to figure out what type this turns into:

```
Imports System.Xml.Serialization

<XmlRootAttribute("TABLE")> _
Public Class MyCollection
    <XmlElement("DATA")> _
    Public Property MyCollection() As MyItem()

End Class

Public Class MyItem
 Public Property Surname() as String
End Class
```

I'm trying to manipulate MyItem's in the MyCollection and then serializing them again into the XML file (keeping TABLE as root element and DATA as XmlElement's within TABLE)

However I'm struggling to figure out what I'm dealing with in the first place so I know how to remove/add/update data within MyCollection. Looping through it is no problem, converting it to a List(Of T) neither and changing MyItem in there, but for the life of me I can't get it back to the original layout with the new data.

Any advice?

Comment: So far doing this in the loop: MyCol.MyCollection = New MyItem() { itemIChanged } gives me the right outcome, but only shows 1 item cause I'm not adding a list of objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it is a normal array. By doing the following I could add all the fixed items to my deserializer:

```
Dim FixedCollection as New MyCollection
Dim NewCollection(MyCol.Count) as MyItem
Dim i As Integer = 0
For Each _item As MyItem In MyCol
     'Fix Stuff
     NewCollection(i) = _item
     i += 1
Next

FixedCollection.MyCollection = NewCollection
```